# Does Snowflake charge me for queries with WAREHOUSE_SIZE=NULL?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to reduce the costs of our queries from Snowflake. In the docs, there is a [detailed explanation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-overview.html) about the credits per second by the size of the used warehouse. When I look at the history tab in the web console, or at the 'snowflake.account_usage.query_history' view, I see that some of the queries have NULL value in the WAREHOUSE_SIZE column (commit statements, desc table etc.). Does anyone know how this type of queries is charged? maybe they are free?

This doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries without a warehouse listed are not charged via the compute credits. These types of queries are using the "cloud services" layer in Snowflake and are charged differently.

Query to determine how much and if cloud services are being used.

```
use schema snowflake.account_usage;

select query_type, sum(credits_used_cloud_services) cs_credits, count(1) num_queries
from query_history
where true
and start_time >= timestampadd(day, -1, current_timestamp)
group by 1
order by 2 desc
limit 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

The result of any query is available for the following 24 hours through the Service Layer in the Result Cache. Therefore, queries that appear to have run without any Warehouse, do Not effectively use any Warehouse.

However, it doesn't necessarily mean that the Warehouse it was supposed to be used otherwise, was Not running at that time.
Say, for example, another query 'Q1' was executed within "your" warehouse 'MyWH' just before you ran your 'Q2': while yours will hit the cache without needing 'MyWH' running, 'Q1' will still cause 'MyWH' to resume and therefore consume credits.

More details on Snowflake Caching are available here: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Caching-in-Snowflake-Data-Warehouse